# Concurrency issue

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, multithreading, concurrency

We are creating a client server application using WPF/C# with SQL. Here we are generating a unique number b checking DB(To get the last maximum number) and with that max value, we are increment '1' and storing the value in DB. At this time another user also working on the same screen and creating unique numbers, in some case the the unique numbers gets duplicated and throws exception.

We found this is a concurrency issue.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also would you mind posting some code to better illustrate your approach?

Comment: The clients are how generated a numbers always?, And this number is saved in DB in the same table always?

Comment: The general idea is that this generation procedure should be implemented on the server rather than on the client. To give you a more detailed explanation I need to know at least what database system you use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, We have follwed Singleton pattern with lock to resolver this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not in any way answer this question. Please post a more complete answer detailing the steps you took to solve it, otherwise this answer and possibly question has little value for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, fetching a number out, adding one, and hoping it still isn't in use is a thread-race and a race between multiple clients - and should be avoided.

Options:

- use an IDENTITY column in the database, and let the database generate the value itself during INSERT; the database server knows how to do this safely and reliably
- if that isn't possible, you might want to delay this code until you are ready to INSERT so it is all part of a single database operation - and even then, if it isn't in a "serializable transaction" (with key-range read locks, etc), then you would have to loop on "get the max, increment, try to insert but note that we might have lost a race, so only insert if the value doesn't exist - which it might; repeat from start if unsuccessful"
- alternatively, you could create the new record when you first need the number (even though the rest of the data isn't available), noting that you might still need the "loop until successful" approach

Frankly, the IDENTITY column approach is the simplest.